# why the return type of cleanup function is void and not int

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Why the return type of module_exit() function or cleanup_module() function is void and not int as of the module_init() function or init_module function.

What will happen when an error occurs while de-registering operations.

Comment: What would you expect the caller to do with an error code from a cleanup function?

Comment: So, you mean there is no significance of the error code .. What if the module was not loaded due to some reason and we try to load module again

Comment: when you will do rmmod, it will call module_exit() and it will free memory and in this what is need to return anything to OS. while in case of module_init() insmod should tell to OS about whether module is inserted or not.